# need absolute measures in liquid layout

Tags: css

I have two child divs in a parent div. first child div A has an absolute height and second div B should take the rest of the height available. How to do this? Basically for div, I want height like (100% - 37px)

```
    <style>
    #C{
    height:100%;
width:500px;
    }

#A{
height:37px;
width:100%;
}

#B{
height: ????;
width:100%
}
    </style>

    <div id="C">
    <div id="A"></div>
    <div id="B"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: css3 calc works fine in this case but thats only for the FF4. I want a solution for webkit based browsers, (even if the solution works only for webkit based browser)

Answer (score 1):

@alter, for rest on the height you need to give `padding` to the `div B` according to the height of `div` `A`

```
#B{
 padding-top:37px;
}
```

for [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/sW5DB/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve that is to give the parent div a min-height and then give div B a min-height of (min-height - 37)px. See code below

```
#C{min-height:600px; width:500px;}
#A{height:37px; width:100%;}
#B{min-height:563px; width:100%}
```

Sample Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #C{min-height:600px; width:500px; background-color:yellow;}
    #A{height:37px; width:100%; background-color:blue;}
    #B{min-height:563px; width:100%; background-color:black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="C">
    <div id="A"></div>
    <div id="B"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added color to the divs just to differentiate them